# Is it possible to change uri-parsing-mode to relaxed-with-raw-query on a per route basis?

Tags: scala, spray

Is it possible to change `uri-parsing-mode` to `relaxed-with-raw-query` on a per route basis? If I change it in `application.conf` it is changed for all routes, but I only need it in one route

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, because parsing is done before routing, so the decision has already been made. What you can do, however, is switching `spray.can.server.raw-request-uri-header = on`. This will add a custom header to every request which you can inspect in the route where you are interested in the raw details.

See https://github.com/spray/spray/blob/master/spray-can/src/main/resources/reference.conf#L76 for the description of the setting.

Comment: Ok thanks, there's the possibility that one client sends GET requests that are too long. In an edge case it happens that the URI get's truncated in a way that it ends with a "%". I want to handle such long requests in a special way. Spray sends out a 400 per default.  As a second attempt I tried to use a custom Exception or Rejection handler, but this seems also to be to late. Do you have any suggestions for a custom handling of invalid requests without loosing the nice "parameter/parameters" directives in the routes when using "relaxed-with-raw-query"?

Comment: You could rewrite the request before it gets to the `parameter` directive. You could wrap the affected parts with a custom directive that - by any custom logic you need - rewrites the broken url into a valid one. See http://spray.io/documentation/1.2.2/spray-routing/basic-directives/mapRequest/ as a building block for such a directive.

Comment: Thanks for the hints! Unfortunately this does not work in the case of an invalid Uri (e.g. ending with a %), because the request query parser of spray seems to run before that. I tried mapRequest and also mapRequestContext. In the case of a valid url the directives are executed but not if the URI ends with a % for example